# Sound switching from 5.1 to 2.0 / Solution?

Tags: audio, motherboard

Hope someone can help me with this problem I'm having.

- I have a **DQ45CB** motherboard.
- I have connected a **2.0** left and right speakers through the green jack, and in the pink one i have a subwoofer with a center speaker.
- I can have only 1 audio player opened, and when I open a new tab in chrome or any browser my sound automatically switches to **2.0** and my subwoofer and center speaker isn't working at that moment.
- When I close it down it switches back on after 3 secs.
- I can't have 2 tabs or a media player opened at the same time.

How can I force the PC to play **5.1** all the time without stutters?

Comment: this is a really strange behavior.

Comment: What is name/version of app? Is this app support more then stereo output? Can you set output in it preferences?

Comment: I have SoundMax 6.0. There are 3 options - Stereo, Quadraphonic, and 5.1. **Found out one more thing. If i don't enable equalization , my sub and C Speaker also doesn't work.**

Answer (score 0):

Is it on windows? `win+x -> control panels -> sound -> playback tab`, here click your speakers and double click or right click -> properties.

In this window, its last tab, `Advanced`and here **uncheck** "allow applications to take exclusive control..."

it looks like this, u need to **uncheck** this.

[speaker properties windows](http://www.abyssmedia.com/isound7/images/sound-card-settings.png)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it didnt work. Tried to play 2 youtubes in different tabs and still the same and now i have to restart chrome to bass to work. Before it automatically turned on. Iv'e never seen anything like this before. also i have noticed that some bad quality songs don't play my L and R speakers, only the Bass and Center.